# Setting noAccessToProcedureBodies using a DriverManagerDataSource bean

Tags: mysql, spring, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jdbctemplate

Hi all fellow Java Geeks,

I have lots of stored procedures in a MySQL database, which I can call successfully from .NET. However, when calling them from Java Spring `SimpleJdbcCall.execute()` I get an exception telling me that the user doesn't have the privilege to do so. But that is clearly not the case since the same user can access it both from CLI and .NET.

I would therefore like to set this parameter:

```
noAccessToProcedureBodies=true
```

However, when adding the parameter in my url in the connector bean below, it thinks that the trailing characters are a part of the database name.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value> 
    </property>

    <property name="username">
        <value>user</value>
    </property>

    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1:3306/database/?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true</value>
    </property>

    <property name="password">
        <value>powerpass</value>
    </property>

</bean>
```

I have been looking at overriding the [`getConnectionProperties`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.html#getConnectionProperties%28%29) method, but I don't think that's the right approach?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer myself, and it's working.

Instead of having an ending slash `"database/?noAccess..."` one should leave it:

```
<property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1:3306/database?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true</value>
</property>
```

Hope that help someone!